# Cython: Efficiently loop over list with multiple types

Tags: loops, cython

I have a Python function that loops over a list and I want to convert it to Cython for performance gain.

The lists it accepts contain a mix of strings, integers, and floats, so I'm not sure how to statically type the variables involved (I don't know C).

What would be the most efficient way to implement something like this in Cython?

Comment: What are you doing with those Python objects (because that's what the list contains) - besides iterating?

Comment: @hpaulj Pushing to different stacks on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be hoping for a C type that has all the flexibility of the Python object, but is somehow magically faster.

There is basically a good option and a bad option here:

- The good option is to accept that such a type doesn't really exist.

  Therefore, you should leave your data extracted from the list untyped so that it remains a regular Python object. Not everything in Cython needs to be typed - the vast majority of Python code should run unchanged.

  It might be worth typing your list as `list`, since Cython can generate slightly more efficient loops when it knows the iterable is a list.
- The bad option is to use a feature of C called a `union` which represents a variable that is one of a limited number of dissimilar types. I am not recommending this (especially for someone that doesn't know C already) because there is no "easy" Cython wrapping (you'll have to dive directly into the C details). You will find handling strings in a `union` particularly challenging.

  Pursue this option at your own peril.